# Taking a screenshot of a remote desktop using Sikuli

Tags: remote-desktop, sikuli, psexec

I have the following Java code which I am using to capture a screenshot:

```
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Screenshot{
                public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
                {
                                Screen screen = new Screen();
                                ImageIO.write(screen.capture(screen).getImage(), "png", new File("D:\\myScreen.png"));
                }
}
```

I compile the piece of code using:

```
javac -classpath .;sikulixapi-2.0.4.jar Screenshot.java
```

and run it with:

```
java -classpath .;sikulixapi-2.0.4.jar Screenshot
```

I tried to run it remotely, using

```
psexec \\xx.xx.xxx.xxx -w "D:\Sikuli" java -classpath .;sikulixapi-2.0.4.jar Screenshot
```

The result is not the picture of the remote screen, but only a black background.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

To check wether you principally could get a shot of the remote screen this way, you can use what SikuliX uses internally: java.awt.Robot

try this:

```
import java.awt.*;
...
BufferedImage img = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500))
```

... and then your coding to store the image somewhere.

If the image is black, then you have a problem with the monitor setup on the remote system. It must be non-headless (real screen) and Robot must have access to an unlocked screen.

RaiMan from SikuliX

Comment: I am looking for a solution that works with a remote desktop connection to a headless virtual machine. I found this article very useful: https://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/testing-with/running/via-rdp/keeping-computer-unlocked.html, but I am still trying to figure out a way to trigger remotely the execution of the test suite.